# When using PHP's crypt() function to create a bcrypt hash, do I need a salt?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, cryptography, bcrypt

I understand that PHP's crypt() function works like so:

```
crypt($password,$salt);
```

And that to create a bcrypt hash(which is considered very secure) the format is:

```
crypt("$2y$15$password",$salt);
```

Where $2y specifies the use of bcrypt, and 15 is the number of rounds, and it should be above 10.

Here's my question. Running:

```
crypt("$2y$15$password");
```

in my understanding, generates a nice big random salt and adds it to the hash, and when comparing passwords, this is extracted automatically. This would mean that I wouldn't have to have a salt field in my table, or generate a salt independently. Is this secure and correct?

For example, when I run:

```
$test = "Hello";
echo crypt("$2y$15$test") . "\n";
```

I get:

```
 $6$R59d/nemygl0$/Gk6s57K2eFAkH4BWDGYhfdhbYGcqz.GRbD7qGDKOlhE5Lk.kgCoGQo/sDCCf1VDffdh7jtXPn/9rsexwrpFk1
```

Where the first 6 refers to some algorithm number, the next bit between the two $ is the salt, and the bit after that is the hash. Is this correct?

Also, what is the syntax for comparing this hash to another for verification?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think crypt as you're using it uses SHA-512.

You probably forgot to pass $test as parameter in your crypt().

According to php [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) you should pass the password as first argument (without any prefix) and then pass the salt as second argument with the $2y$15 prefix and a 22 characters salt. E.g.

```
crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `crypt()` should be used like this:

```
$hashvalue = crypt($password, $cryptParams);
```

whereas the salt must be generated by yourself and is part of $cryptParams.

```
$bcryptAlgo = '$2y';
$cost = '$15';
$salt = '$' . functionThatGenerates22CharRandomSalt();
$cryptParams = $bcryptAlgo . $cost . $salt;
```

One of the difficulties is to generate a valid, unique and unpredictable salt. The best you can do is to read from the operating systems random source.

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` ready, to simplify this task. I strongly recommend to use this excellent api, there is also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) available for earlier PHP versions. If you want to know more about how to use crypt, have a look at this [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt).

Your cost parameter of 15 is quite high, use it if you can afford this much of time, but today a number of 10 is ok.